# Save Record Multiple Times Different Parameters Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an order model with a `product_id` foreign key and users can specify `delivery_day` on a single form.

If a user selects `Monday` and `Friday`, I'd like to save two records of the order with different `delivery_day` attributes but the same `product_id`.

## controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
def new
  @product = Product.find(params[:product])
  @day = params[:day]
  @order = Order.new(:user_id => current_user.id, :product_id => @product.id, :delivery_day => @day) 
end

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save
    redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

## views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_id %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :product_id %>
  </div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :delivery_day %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :delivery_day %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

I looked around, but couldn't find an answer to this. Not sure if nested associations are overkill (like [coccoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)) because I'm just trying create multiple records of `order` with different `delivery_day` parameters.

Comment: I think what you could do is build an array from your checkbox field and iterate over the array to create a new Order for each day.

Comment: @ccai thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try - if you could give an example code, that would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the day names as checkboxes using a loop

```
<% Date::DAYNAMES.each do |day| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag "<%= day %>" %><br>
    <%= check_box_tag "delivary_days[]" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Now, receive the selected day names from your controller as `params[:delivary_days]`, then manipulate the result accordingly.

In your controller:

```
params[:delivary_days].each do |day|
  Order.create(other_parameters, :delivery_day => day)
end
```

I suggest you to go to the *[check_box_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)* for necessary options.

Answer (score 0):

Update your form as

```
<%= f.label :delivery_day %><br>
<%= f.select(:delivery_day,options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES), {multiple: true, data: {placeholder: "Select Days"}}) %>
```

Update your controller create action as:

```
def create
  delivery_days = order_params[:delivery_day]
  delivery_days.each do |day|
    @order = Order.new(order_params.merge({delivery_day: day}))
    render :new unless @order.save
  end
  redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully
end
```

Hope It will help you. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i tried this out, but noticed you cannot select multiple days with the drop down. I think I need to use check boxes.

Comment: you can select multiple with dropdown. params[:delivery_days] will be an array.Check your params in request and post here please. Have a look on this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: thanks i think i figured it out. How can I add a time for each day as well?

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work `<div class="field"> <%= label_tag "Time" %><br> <%= time_select "delivery_times[]", "time" %> </div>`

Comment: I think you are making mistake in terms of params. Can you paste here your params from console log which you are getting from request?

Answer (score 0):

You should take checked element from form as array of selected element. Something like this `order[:delivery_day][]`.

You are using `check_box` tag in your form this might cause some issue. Because there is a gotcha while you update through `check_box` tag, You can read [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box).

So better you use [check_box_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) helper as suggested in above link.

Try change your check_box code something like below:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= hidden_feild_tag "order[delivery_day][]", nil %>
  <%= ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thurs", "fri", "sat", "sun"].each do |day| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "order[delivery_day][]", day, true_or_false_if_selected_before_add_condition %>
    <%= label_tag day.capitalize %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So you will get params selected in `order[delivery_day][]` params. If it include blank remove them with ruby method.

And in your create and update method try create product S BELOW:

```
order[delivery_day].each do |day|
  Order.create(other_params, :delivery_day => day)
end
```